# JHipster Microservice Centralization without using Docker compose or any Docker container, need assistance

Tags: microservices, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

Currently the scenario is I am trying to implement

I used **Jhipster** Registry app directly from git-hub to use it as Eureka registry and Spring-Cloud-Config server(be default feature though).

I need to centralize the configurations of micro-service-apps' configurations files in **Jhipster** registry.

All these we have to do without using Docker as current project doesn't uses Docker.
To do that I made changes to
*bootstrap.yml* file as shown below( to run as composite profile though native type with local file system as we don't have access to production git repository. So chose file-system only with **dev /composite** profile only.
Currently my *boostrap.yml* looks as below

```
spring:
  application:
    name: jhipster-registry
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        
        bootstrap: true
        composite:
          - type: native #git
            
            search-locations: file:/C:/Jhipster_Eureka/jhipster-registry-master/central-config/
            
        prefix: /config
      fail-fast: true
      
      name: jhipster-registry
      profile: composite
```

I have also created a *gateway.yml* file under central-config folder( gateway is one of micro-service sample app whose configuration I am trying to centralize, be it eureka client, data-source everything which comes under by default to **application-dev.yml** in the **Jhipster** micro-service gateway app I generated.)
by stating all configuration like below
**gateway.yml**

```
   server:
  port: 8888
management:
  health:
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
# ===================================================================
# JHipster Sample Spring Cloud Config.
# ===================================================================

# Property used on app startup to check the config server status

configserver:
  name: JHipster Registry config server
  status: Connected to the JHipster Registry config server!

# Default JWT secret token (to be changed in production!)
jhipster:
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        # It is recommended to encrypt the secret key in Base64, using the `base64-secret` property.
        # For compabitibily issues with applications generated with older JHipster releases,
        # we use the non Base64-encoded `secret` property here.
        # secret: my-secret-key-which-should-be-changed-in-production-and-be-base64-encoded
        # The `base64-secret` property is recommended if you use JHipster v5.3.0+
        # (you can type `echo 'secret-key'|base64` on your command line)
        base64-secret: bXktc2VjcmV0LWtleS13aGljaC1zaG91bGQtYmUtY2hhbmdlZC1pbi1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLWFuZC1iZS1iYXNlNjQtZW5jb2RlZAo=

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include:
      - swagger

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/



  datasource:
  type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conference?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  username: root
  password: root
  hikari:
    poolName: Hikari
    auto-commit: false
    data-source-properties:
      cachePrepStmts: true
      prepStmtCacheSize: 250
      prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
      useServerPrepStmts: true

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    liquibase:
      # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
      contexts: dev
```

Issue#1
If I run my registry it's coming up properly without any issue. If I try to run "gateway" micro-service app without defining data-source  definitions mentioned in it's own configuration file(application-dev.yml) it's failing at runtime.

Exception Stack trace during runtime

```
2020-08-06 21:45:58.301  WARN 28804 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I am surprised how eureka instance it picked up from that **gateway.yml** file but not the data source, so what went wrong here?

Issue#2

In the gateway.app yml `server.port:8888` is mentioned, but would it be spring-cloud-config-server's port or the micro-service app port e.g., 8083
.
I observed if i try to alter that port from 8888 to 8083 it's giving error at runtime not able to find discovery client, what's the issue or am i still      missing something configuration-wise?

Please let me know if the query is detailed enough now to respond.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou as per your kind suggestion I have edited and re-phrased my query as above, please have a look and share your inputs please

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for your response. Even though I am using composite I observed it's still able to reach gateway.yml at central-config location, which in turn is used by Spring Cloud Config server as per my understanding. however I may change that to dev profile, no issue, but still where can this data source part be included as central configuration so that my gateway micro-service app able to load it during it's startup post fetching from Registry app.So my issue# 1 and 2 both on that part you mentioned you would come back if understood you correctly .

Comment: So, your properties files are still incorrectly indented, this could be a reason of failure, unless you fix it I'm still in doubt. Could you share a git repo? In your gateway you don't need any application-*.yml files, you can delete them and centralize them in the config server as long as your bootstrap.yml points to your config server and uses a fail-fast:true

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I am trying to share my current Jhipster-registry app via git repo and microservcie gateway app too, sharing link here for your quick review and then probably you can let me know what might have gone wrong. The git hub link for registry app-- https://github.com/debjupiter18/Registry and for gateway micro-service app -- https://github.com/debjupiter18/gateway, uploaded all config files currently using to centralize gateway app through registry app, please check and let me know if any gaps

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have tried your suggestion and that data source error gone post proper indentation of the gateway.yml finally. But a new error observed regarding liquibase, please let me know if any configuration on that part of liquibase missing. Pasting the error below.

Comment: Liquibase error here it is ERROR 23788 --- [ gateway-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum        config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster was: 8:9bf75aca02e1c4157cc1268a96e34b65 but is now: 8:c5bfc567913b118109a43e981cd02883one ne wissue

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I tried this option in my gateway.yml at central-config folder mentioned here spring.liquibase.drop-first: true, the error mentioned above is gone, hope this is fine

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have raised another query, can you kindly assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63389371/how-to-encrypt-jasypt-encryptor-pasword-property-while-using-in-jhipster-registry

Comment: @GaëlMarziou it's accepted now. can you kindly assist me the query if any lead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63389371/how-to-encrypt-jasypt-encryptor-pasword-property-while-using-in-jhipster-registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is absolutely NOT required for JHipster micro services architecture using jhipster-registry, your use case is well supported and the issues you encountered are only due to your configuration errors.

`gateway.yml` is not indented correctly so property names for `datasource` do not match and this is why you get this error about being unable to find JDBC driver.

The `eureka` block in the middle of the `spring` block completely broke it and anyway eureka config is shared by all apps so it should be placed in `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml`.

`gateway.yml` as any other files that are in environment repository (`central-config` folder when using native) must be exactly the same format as your local application.yml files.

If you are not comfortable with YAML files you could switch to normal properties.

About file naming in native repository, [Spring Cloud Config Server doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_environment_repository) says:

> If the repository is file-based, the server creates an Environment from application.yml (shared between all clients) and foo.yml (with foo.yml taking precedence). If the YAML files have documents inside them that point to Spring profiles, those are applied with higher precedence (in order of the profiles listed). If there are profile-specific YAML (or properties) files, these are also applied with higher precedence than the defaults.

So basically it means that in your `central-config` folder you should have these files:

- `application.yml`: all properties common to all apps when no profile is set
- `application-dev.yml`: all properties common to all apps when dev profile is set. This is where you will put the JWT secret for dev, the url for dev Eureka server (often localhost)
- `application-prod.yml`: all properties common to all apps when prod profile is set. This is where you will put the JWT secret for prod, the url for prod Eureka server
- `gateway.yml`: all properties of gateway app when no profile is set
- `gateway-dev.yml`: all properties of gateway app when dev profile is set. This is where you will put dev datasource
- `gateway-prod.yml`: all properties of gateway app when prod profile is set. This is where you will put prod datasource

So when your gateway bootstraps with dev profile, it will gets a combination of application.yml, application-dev.yml, gateway.yml and gateway-dev.yml

This mechanism can work only if you follow the naming convention `{app name}-{profile}.yml`

So, having named a file `application-dev-gateway.yml` just meant properties common to all apps with `dev-gateway` profile which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: Actually I forgot to share entire project , to put in a nutshell I have used bootstrap.yml for Registry app project at /config folder only dint mix it with the central-config folder,. yes central-config folder having other files under registry github url what you saw, but using only for now gateway.yml from central-config folder. tis project running in widnows through mvnw command using dev and composite profile. gateway app github url if you observe i am using mainly bootstrap.yml only from gateway microservice app project,configurations you saw probably already, if tis input is fine with you

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind responses and patiently dealing with my issue. this seems to be of great help, will tweak this onto current implementation and retest and will confirm back soon.